# Share point charts from list

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list that contains a list of projects and their technology. Example.

P1 - Java
P2 - SAP
P3 - Oracle
P4 - Java
p5 - Oracle

I want to be able to represent the Tech distribution in a share point pie chart web part.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to create another table to reflect the actual numbers i.e.

Java - 2
SAP - 1
Oracle -2

In excel I would simply create a table that had formulas calculating the numbers so if the techs changed then the pie chart would dynamically change as well.

I'm brainstorming ways I could get the pie chart in SP to change dynamically if the Techs in the first list change or if more projects are added.

Thanks for your ideas.